# Emacs equivalents of Vim's dd,o,O

Tags: vim, emacs, editor, editing

I am currently playing around with emacs and happy with most of the concepts. But I really adored the convenience of the three vim commands: dd,o,O
Hopefully you can tell me how to mirror them in emacs :)

> **dd** - deletes whole line, including newline, no matter where the cursor is.

I found something similar to do the trick:

> C-a C-k C-k

While `C-a` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, the first `C-k` kills the text, the second one kills the newline. The only problem is that this is not working on empty lines where I only need to type `C-k` which is quite inconvenient as I have to use different commands for the same task: killing a line.

> **o / O** - creates a new empty line below / above cursor and moves cursor to the new line, indented correctly

Well, `C-a C-o` is nearly like `O`, just the idention is missing. `C-e C-o` creates an empty line below the current but does not move the cursor.

Are there any better solutions to my problems or do I have to learn Lisp and define new commands to fulfill my needs?

Comment: I think best method for new line is this http://superuser.com/a/331661 (C-e C-j)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For `o` and `O`, here are a few functions I wrote many years ago:

```
(defun vi-open-line-above ()
  "Insert a newline above the current line and put point at beginning."
  (interactive)
  (unless (bolp)
    (beginning-of-line))
  (newline)
  (forward-line -1)
  (indent-according-to-mode))

(defun vi-open-line-below ()
  "Insert a newline below the current line and put point at beginning."
  (interactive)
  (unless (eolp)
    (end-of-line))
  (newline-and-indent))

(defun vi-open-line (&optional abovep)
  "Insert a newline below the current line and put point at beginning.
With a prefix argument, insert a newline above the current line."
  (interactive "P")
  (if abovep
      (vi-open-line-above)
    (vi-open-line-below)))
```

You can bind `vi-open-line` to, say, *M-insert* as follows:

```
(define-key global-map [(meta insert)] 'vi-open-line)
```

For `dd`, if you want the killed line to make it onto the kill ring, you can use this function that wraps `kill-line`:

```
(defun kill-current-line (&optional n)
  (interactive "p")
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (let ((kill-whole-line t))
      (kill-line n))))
```

For completeness, it accepts a prefix argument and applies it to `kill-line`, so that it can kill much more than the "current" line.

You might also look at the source for [`viper-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/viper/index.html) to see how it implements the equivalent `dd`, `o`, and `O` commands.

Comment: Wow great, thanks. Works like a charm :) Just the `vi-open-line-above` does not indent. Any ideas?

Comment: I added `(indent-according-to-mode)` in `vi-open-line-above` below `(forward-line -1)`. This does the trick :)

Comment: Funny, I was in the middle of editing it again when you noted that you found the solution. As you can tell, this is old code that I don't use often. I wrote it when I first learning Emacs Lisp. This question gave me an excuse to freshen it.

Answer (score 25):

For dd, use "kill-whole-line", which is bound to "C-S-backspace" by default in recent versions of Emacs.

I should add that I myself use [whole-line-or-region.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WholeLineOrRegion) more often, since `C-w` is easier to type than `C-S-backspace`.

Answer (score 25):

```
C+e C+j
```

According to [the emacs manual docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html). That gets you a new line and indentation.

Comment: if you are in the middle of a sentence or line, and `c+j` it will put the rest of the line on the new line. it's like hitting `return` in the middle of the line. we want to add a blank line below the current cursor position.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [macro](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/acs/rpinfo/common/Computing/Consulting/Software/Emacs/Hints/macros.html) and [bind it to a key sequence](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html). No need to learn any emacslisp yet.

Answer (score 2):

I know, this response is not straight to the point, however like a vim user, I found that Spacemacs is the most functional emacs starter pack to move from vim to emacs. You can configure it to be vim like, emacs like or hybrid.

http://spacemacs.org/

Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

After a couple of searching and experimenting, I came to a conclusion based on the other answers that the alternatives are the following:

- `dd` command on Vim: `C-S-backspace` on Emacs
- `o` command on Vim: `C-e C-j` on Emacs
- `O` command on Vim: `C-a C-j C-p` on Emacs

Yes, emacs sometimes have some "expressive" command combinations to do a couple of things, but they do make a lot of sense sometimes!

And if you think about it, emacs sometimes also simplifies things when vim doesn't. When you want to select the whole text in a file, you do `ggVG` on Vim while on Emacs is simply `C-x h`!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I addressed the issue of Emacs's lack of a vi-like "O" command:

```
(defadvice open-line (around vi-style-open-line activate)
  "Make open-line behave more like vi."
  (beginning-of-line)
  ad-do-it
  (indent-according-to-mode))
```

With this in place, I've never really felt the need for a corresponding version of vi's "o" command.  C-n C-o does the trick.

As for the "dd" command, that grated a little at first, but I eventually came around to Emacs's way of doing things.  Anyway, when I want to delete several lines at once, which is often the case, I just do it using the region (C-a C-SPC, go to the other end of the text I want to delete, C-w).  Or if I can eyeball the number of lines I want to delete, I'll do eg. M-9 C-k to delete nine lines at once.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Viper-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode), [Vimpulse](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vimpulse.el) or [Vim Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VimMode), Emacs keybindings are just not as ergonomic.

Comment: This sounds awkward to me. If I want to use vim, then I use vim not emacs.

Comment: Emacs' keybindings may(!) not be ergonomic, but for me at least, vi's modal **** grates on my brain.

Comment: @eteubert not awkward at all. just think of emacs as the 3rd (or 4th) mode. it actually feels natural once you've picked up emacs and everything resides within emacs.

Answer (score 0):

All of these are great. Here's a couple more.

https://stable.melpa.org/#/crux
https://github.com/bbatsov/crux

Crux doesn't map any keybinds it leaves you to decide the keybindings but here are the relevant functions you can keybind as suggested or change as you wish.

```
Function:                   Keymap:     Description:
---------------------------------------------------------
crux-kill-whole-line        Super-k     Kill whole line
crux-smart-open-line-above  Super-O     Insert an empty line above & indent
crux-smart-open-line        Super-o     Insert an empty line and indent
```

You could of course use something else such as C-c o / M-c o or whatever other keybinding makes sense to you personally.  See the crux github for the instructions.

Alternative is to consider Doom Emacs which has Evil Mode installed and turned on by default.  Then 99.999% of the ViM Keybindings you are familiar with work much the same way.  You can also install Evil-Mode manually on Vanilla Emacs and even turn it on and off as needed with a keybinding or utilize some minor eLisp to hook Evil-Mode to specific buffer / file-types.

I've been a long time Vi / ViM / Neovim user and I started with Doom. However, lately, I am forcing myself to learn to use Emacs the way it was intended and I am learning quite a bit more. The key-chords and default bindings are not as terrible as I thought.  I am learning the muscle memory rather quickly. I just start up Emacs and aside from picking a decent theme, font(s), and disabling the scrollbar, toolbar, menu bar and adding which-key-mode and spacious-padding-mode.  I've not changed much else but install some other packages.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said `C-S-backspace` to kill the current line

For open line above, use `M-m C-o` to keep the indentation (`M-m` puts you to the start of the line *after* indentation)

For open line below, I'm surprised no one has suggested to press the `enter` key to open a line below and drop into it, so do that after moving to the end of the current line `C-e enter`. This is likely to also give you the right indentation, unlike `C-j`